# Installed Spyder using pip under Canopy (OSx), how do i start Spyder?

Tags: python, spyder, canopy

I am on a machine running Yosemite. I manage my python environment with Canopy Enthought. I'm trying to install Spyder, so I don't have to use the Editor that comes with Canopy.

I opened a Canopy terminal and used `pip install spyder` which went fine.

How do I actually start Spyder? When I use `pip list` I can see the Spyder package.

```
spyder
spyder.py
python spyder.py
```

ect. does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`python -c "from spyderlib import start_app; start_app.main()"`

Comment: That does not work. I get errors like this: `File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.1.2730.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 443, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8`

Comment: Hmm, works for me in Yosemite. Are you sure that you are in a Canopy terminal or equivalent? What is your `which python`? See https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-User-Python-be-your-default-Python

Comment: In Canopy terminal for sure. `which python` gives `/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
(Canopy 64bit)`

Comment: In that case I guess I would take the warning at its word. Try exploring http://blog.remibergsma.com/2012/07/10/setting-locales-correctly-on-mac-osx-terminal-application/